# Angularfire2 and updating different objects using data fan-out

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need to update objects in my database, so I do this:

```
const items = af.database.list('/items');
items.update('key-of-some-data1', { size: newSize1 });
items.update('key-of-some-data2', { size: newSize2 });
```

This works like a charm, but I would like to update items with a "data fan-out" as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html

So I do:

```
var updates = {};
updates['key-od-some-data1']= { size: newSize1 };
updates['key-od-some-data2']= { size: newSize2 };
items.update(updates);
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> zone.js:140 Uncaught Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:30:2 caused by: Method requires a key, snapshot, reference, or unwrapped snapshot. Got: object

Is it even possible to update with data fan-out to the database with angularfire2? Does data fan-out work only with the same object key or something?

Comment: do you have an example of how to get the `key` using AF2? I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm running into a TS error when calling `child('/path').push().key();`

Comment: Do you mean 'key' you just created? It's genereated automatically. Try `key=child('/path').push();`[https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: I just got it by doing `items.push('new item').then(res => console.log(res.key));` thanks, anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
const items = af.database.list('/items');
```

with:

```
const items = af.database.object('/items');
```